# ./src/components/Car.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-table/react-table.css' in 'C:\Users\Felix\source\repos\React\car-app\src\components'

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and i need to do a web api app for my licence with this library.
When i start the npm ,it shows me this error:

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-table/react-table.css' in 'C:\Users\Felix\source\repos\React\car-app\src\components'.
Note:Application worked when i returned a simple table,all the backend part works good ,all modals , components are working good ,I installed react-table package ,still it doesn't work.

**Car.js**

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from'react-bootstrap';
import {Button,ButtonToolbar} from'react-bootstrap';
import {AddCarModal} from'./AddCarModal';
import {EditCarModal} from './EditCarModal';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import GlobalSearchComponent from "./GlobalSearchComponent";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactTable from "react-table";





export class Car extends Component
{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={cars:[] ,addModalShow : false, editModalShow :false, filteredData: [],
        columns: [],
        searchInput: ""}
   }
   componentDidMount()
   {
       this.refreshList();

       this.getColumns();

   }
   refreshList()
   {

    fetch('https://localhost:44385/api/car')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data=> {
           this.setState({cars:data});
       }
       );
    }
        componentDidUpdate(){
            this.refreshList();
        }

   deleteCar( carid)
   {
     if(window.confirm('Are you sure?'))
     {
         fetch('https://localhost:44385/api/car/' + carid,{
          method:'DELETE',
          headers :{'Accept' :'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json' 
          }
         })
     }
    }




      getColumns = () => {
        let columns = [
          {
            Header: "Model Name",
            accessor: "modelName",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Model Name"
          },
          {
            Header: "Fuel Type",
            accessor: "fueltype",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Fuel type "
          },
          {
            Header: "Body Type",
            accessor: "bodytype",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Body Type "
          },
          {
            Header: "Price interval",
            accessor: "priceinterval",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Visits "
          },
          {
            Header: "Offroad rank",
            accessor: "offroadrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Offroad rank "
          },
          {
            Header: "Maximum speed interval",
            accessor: "maximumspeedinterval",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Maximum speed interval"
          },
          {
            Header: "Luxury rank",
            accessor: "luxuryrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Luxury rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Reliability rank",
            accessor: "reliabilityrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Reliability rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Safety rank",
            accessor: "safetyrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Safety rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Practicality rank",
            accessor: "practicalityrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Practicality rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Drive rank",
            accessor: "driverank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Drive rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Interior rank",
            accessor: "interiorrank",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Interior rank"
          },
          {
            Header: "Good for city traffic?",
            accessor: "forcity",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Yes or No? "
          },
          {
            Header: "Good for long distance?",
            accessor: "forlong",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Yes or No? "
          },
          {
            Header: "Consumption",
            accessor: "consumption",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Consumption"
          },
          {
            Header: "Electric consumption",
            accessor: "econsumption",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Electric consumption"
          },
          {
            Header: "Engine type",
            accessor: "enginetype",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Engine type"
          },
          {
            Header: "Cylinder number",
            accessor: "cylidnernumber",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Cylinder number"
          },
          {
            Header: "Naturally Aspired or Turbo?",
            accessor: "naot",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: "Naturally Aspired or Turbo?"
          },
          {
            Header: "Number of seats",
            accessor: "seatsnumber",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Number of seats"
          },
          {
            Header: "Cargo space",
            accessor: "cargo",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Cargo space "
          },
          {
            Header: "Options",
            accessor: "option",
            sortable: false,
            show: true,
            displayValue: " Option "
          }
        ];
        this.setState({ columns });
      };



      handleSetData = cars => {
        console.log(cars);
        this.setState({ cars });
      };



      handleSetFilteredData = filteredData => {
        this.setState({ filteredData });
      };

      handleSetSearchInput = searchInput => {
        this.setState({ searchInput });
      };
    render() {

      let{cars,carid,carname,carfuel,carbody,carprice,caroffroad,carspeed,carluxury,carreliability,carsafety,carpracticality,cardrive,carinterior,carcity,cardistance,
        carconsumption,careconsumption,carengine,carcylinder,carnaot,carseats,carcargo, filteredData, columns, searchInput }=this.state;

      const dataToDisplay = searchInput.length ? filteredData : cars;

    let addModalClose=()=> this.setState({addModalShow:false});
        let editModalClose=()=> this.setState({editModalShow:false});
        return(
       <div>
   <GlobalSearchComponent
          cars={this.state.cars}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          handleSetFilteredData={this.handleSetFilteredData}
          handleSetSearchInput={this.handleSetSearchInput}
        />

<Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
<thead>
 <tr>

 <ReactTable
          cars={dataToDisplay}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />

 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{cars.map(cr=>
    <tr key ={cr.id}> 

    <td> {cr.modelName }  </td>
    <td> {cr.fueltype }  </td>
    <td> {cr.bodytype}  </td>
    <td> {cr.priceinterval }  </td>
    <td> {cr.offroadrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.maximumspeedinterval }  </td>
    <td> {cr.luxuryrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.reliabilityrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.safetyrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.practicalityrank}  </td>
    <td> {cr.driverank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.interiorrank }  </td>
    <td> {cr.forcity }  </td>
    <td> {cr.forlong }  </td>
    <td> {cr.consumption }  </td>
    <td> {cr.electricconsumption}  </td>
    <td> {cr.enginetype }  </td>
    <td> {cr.cylindernumber }  </td>
    <td> {cr.naot }  </td>
    <td> {cr.seatsnumber }  </td>
    <td> {cr.cargo }  </td>
    <td>
        <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button 
                   className="mr-2" variant ="info"
                    onClick={()=> this.setState({editModalShow : true , 
                        carid:cr.id, carname:cr.modelName, 
                    carfuel:cr.fueltype,carbody:cr.bodytype,
            carprice:cr.priceinterval,caroffroad:cr.offroadrank,
            carspeed:cr.maximumspeedinterval,  carluxury:cr.luxuryrank,
            carreliability:cr.reliabilityrank,carsafety:cr.safetyrank,
            carpracticality:cr.practicalityrank,cardrive:cr.driverank,
            carinterior:cr.interiorrank,carcity:cr.forcity,
            cardistance:cr.forlong,carconsumption:cr.consumption,
            careconsumption:cr.electricconsumption,carengine:cr.enginetype,
            carcylinder:cr.cylindernumber,carnaot:cr.naot,
            carseats:cr.seatsnumber,carcargo:cr.cargo})}
           >
               Edit 
           </Button>

          <Button className="mr-2"
          onClick={()=> this.deleteCar(cr.id)} 
          variant="danger"
          > Delete</Button>

                <EditCarModal
                       show = {this.state.editModalShow}
                       onHide={editModalClose}
                       carid={carid}
                       carname={carname}
                       carfuel={carfuel}
                       carbody={carbody}
                        carprice={carprice}
                       caroffroad={caroffroad}
                       carspeed={carspeed}
                       carluxury={carluxury}
                       carreliability={carreliability}
                        carsafety={carsafety}
                       carpracticality={carpracticality}
                       cardrive={cardrive}
                       carinterior={carinterior}
                       carcity={carcity}
                       cardistance={cardistance}
                       carconsumption={carconsumption}
                       careconsumption={careconsumption}
                        carengine={carengine}
                        carcylinder={carcylinder}
                        carnaot={carnaot}
                        carseats={carseats}
                         carcargo={carcargo}
              />
             </ButtonToolbar>
         </td>
    </tr>
)}
        </tbody>
 </Table>


 <ButtonToolbar>
     <Button
     variant='primary'
     onClick={()=> this.setState({addModalShow: true})}
     >Add Car </Button>

     <AddCarModal
         show={this.state.addModalShow}
         onHide={addModalClose}
     />
 </ButtonToolbar>







 </div>




    )



    }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Car />, rootElement);
```

**GlobalSearchComponent**

```
    import React from "react";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

export default class GlobalSearchComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredData: [],
      columnSearch: "",
      searchInput: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ searchInput: val }, () => this.globalSearch());
    this.props.handleSetSearchInput(val);
  };

  globalSearch = () => {
    const { searchInput, columnSearch } = this.state;
    let filteredData = this.props.cars.filter(value => {
      if (columnSearch) {
        return value[columnSearch]
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
      }
      return (
        value.modelName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.fueltype.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.bodytype.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.priceinterval.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.offroadrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.maximumspeedinterval.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.luxuryrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.reliabilityrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.safetyrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.practicalityrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.driverank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.interiorrank.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.forcity.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.forlong.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.consumption.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.econsumption.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.enginetype.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.cylindernumber.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.naot.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.seatsnumber.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.cargo.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) 


          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
      );
    });

    this.props.handleSetFilteredData(filteredData);
  };

  setColumnSearch = e => {
    this.setState({ columnSearch: e.target.value }, () => this.globalSearch());
  };

  render() {
    const { columns } = this.props;
    const { columnSearch } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <br />
        <Input
          size="large"
          name="searchInput"
          value={this.state.searchInput || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          label="Search"
        />
        <select
          onChange={e => {
            e.persist();
            this.setColumnSearch(e);
          }}
          value={columnSearch}
        >
          <option value=""> All columns</option>
          {columns.map(col => {
            return <option value={col.accessor}>{col.Header}</option>;
          })}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for help !
  EDIT:The problem was that react-table needs v-6 to have react-table.css

Comment: Where did you use react-table or simple table? I can't find neither of them.

Comment: copied the last table,sorry,i updated the code from Cars.js

Comment: Have you checked if there is react-table.css in nodemodules/react-table directory?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the line `import "react-table/react-table.css";` in car.js?
I checked the examples of react-table in github, but I couldn't find the line.

Comment: i've found the error ,it was the version of the react-table ,i needed version 6 for my project,thanks for help